# After Changing the text Content of an H# element can't access a constant that was assigned to a span,even after returning the innerHTML back to normal

Tags: javascript, html, web, frontend

I started learning web development not too long ago and I stumbled upon an issue.

It goes as follows:

1.I have an H# element with a span(with an id)

2.I assigned a constant to the span.

3.I changed the H element's textContent to show a different result.

4.I changed the InnerHTML of the H element back to the original format.

5.I assigned a new text content to the constant from step #2.

6. I tried to debug.log the H element and the span element cannot be changed.

```
assume exists:
    <h2 id="h2-id">Some text:<span id="span-id">Content</span>!</h2>

Example:
const result = document.querySelector("#span-id");
const resultText = document.querySelector("#h2-id");
resultText.textContent = "Something else.";
resultText.innerHTML = 'Some text:<span id="span-id">Content</span>!';
result.textContent = "New Content";
debug.log(resultText.textContent);//prints: Some text:Content! not Some text:New Content!.
```

It works if I assign the (previously)constant as a regular variable and query it again after restoring the InnerHTML, tho I do not understand since it was queried initially by an ID isn't it supposed to "re-attach" to the H element after I restore Its contents?

I assume js looks at the reassigned innerHTML as a new "Object" so it doesn't recognize it?

Comment: you have a typo `resultText.InnerHTML` this won't do anything. It should be `resultText.innerHTML`

Comment: Yes, `result` refers to the original span that doesn't exist in the DOM anymore. It won't update itself with the new element, even if it has the same ID.

Comment: yeah it doesn't  matter if you do `result.textContent = "New Content";` the element doesn't exist anymore after you overwrote the `innerHTML` of your `<h2>` `resultText.innerHTML = 'Some text:<span id="span-id">Content</span>!';` that `<span>` is a new element

Comment: understood DallogFheir much appreciated, figured as much..
Is there an option to go around it without reassigning it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in some of the comments, setting innerHTML overwrites what was previously on the DOM and the `result` variable points to a node that no longer exist.

A way around this (for this specific use case) would be to use a function. Something like

```js
function getSpan() {
  return document.querySelector("#span-id");
}

getSpan().textContent = "New Content";
```

This way, calling the `getSpan()` function will always check the DOM for the span and not use what was already stored in memory.

Comment: makes a lot of sense, thank you!